# Word, Save as PDF cuts off right and bottom

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2016

I suspect the following problem to be a user-specific setting (because it happens to one user with all documents whereas the same documents work fine with a different user) but could not find anything in Word options that might cause this:

When exporting a documnet from Word to PDF format, the output is too small and is cut off at the right and bottom. More specifically, the produced PDF has page size 168.1 mm by 237.7 mm instead of the document page size (A4 = 210 mm by 297 mm). The text content appears in its correct size, hence is cut off at the right and bottom end. Note that 168.1 mm by 237.7 mm is exactly 80% of A4 dimensions!

The problem does not occur with *print* to PDF, only with *save* as PDF. Before testing the corresponding native menu item, the first observation of the problem was when a Word macro produced bad output, so I suspected that the macro call

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=PdfName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportAllDocument, CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks,
        UseISO19005_1:=False
```

might be missing an important parameter, but https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat doesn't suggest that any of the left out parameters might cause the problem when left at its default value.

Where shold I look next?

Comment: If you can afford it, try to reset word to default settings: https://www.process.st/how-to/reset-microsoft-word-to-default-settings/

Comment: @KJ I tried reproducing the problem by playing with my own display settings (even with different settings per monitor), but the problem would not happen for me. On the other hand, the affected user *did* have 125% in use, but changing to 100% did not help. On the third hand, several other users certainly also use some zoom setting and have not reported similar problems so far ...

Comment: In Word *Options > Advanced*, scroll to the "Show Document Content" section and enable "Show Text Boundaries". If there are elements outside the dotted lines, that might be the problem.